# nil pointer dereference error while trying to initialize a struct with pointer fields

Tags: go, null

Defined struct type:

```
type ValidateTemplateQuery struct {
    TemplateURL  *string `json:"template_url" valid:"optional"`
    TemplateBody *string `json:"template_body" valid:"optional"`
}
```

Trying to initiate with mock values:

```
action := &ValidateTemplateQuery{
    TemplateURL:  *("TemplateURLValue"),
    TemplateBody: *("TemplateBodyValue"),
}
```

Error

> getting "panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"

Comment: Pointing to a literal is not a good idea.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi: Your point is meaningless since pointing to a literal is not allowed in Go.

Answer (score 3):

> trying to initiate with mock values

---

Use the address of variables. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    type ValidateTemplateQuery struct {
        TemplateURL  *string `json:"template_url" valid:"optional"`
        TemplateBody *string `json:"template_body" valid:"optional"`
    }

    url := "TemplateURLValue"
    body := "TemplateBodyValue"
    action := &ValidateTemplateQuery{
        TemplateURL:  &url,
        TemplateBody: &body,
    }

    fmt.Println(action, *action.TemplateURL, *action.TemplateBody)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/LZKV2LZ4KiE

Output:

```
&{0x40c138 0x40c140} TemplateURLValue TemplateBodyValue
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Address operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)
>
> For an operand x of type T, the address operation &x generates a
>   pointer of type *T to x. The operand must be addressable, that is,
>   either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation;
>   or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array
>   indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the
>   addressability requirement, x may also be a (possibly parenthesized)
>   composite literal. If the evaluation of x would cause a run-time
>   panic, then the evaluation of &x does too.